# FSCalendar content getting squished when I switch scope to month

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, fscalendar

My FSCalendar's content shrinks when I switch its scope from week to month if there is a view that's constrained to its bottom anchor.

**Here is a quick gif to show what exactly is happening**

[image: GIF]

I have tried everything at this point. Using `calendar.setScope()` instead of `calendar.scope =`, constraining `attachedToCalendarView.topAnchor` to `calendar.bottomAnchor` `calendar.contentView.bottomAnchor`, and `calendar.daysContainer.bottomAnchor`, even turning `attachedToCalendarView` 's constraints on and off depending on whether it's week scope or scope month.

Not sure what else to try. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import FSCalendar

class TestController : UIViewController, FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {

fileprivate weak var calendar: FSCalendar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    setUp()
}


@objc func switchCalendarScope(){
    if self.calendar.scope == FSCalendarScope.month {
        self.calendar.scope = FSCalendarScope.week

    } else {
        self.calendar.scope = FSCalendarScope.month
    }

}

func setUp(){

    let calendar = FSCalendar()
    calendar.dataSource = self
    calendar.delegate = self
    self.calendar = calendar

    self.calendar.scope = .week
    self.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_EN")
    self.calendar.calendarHeaderView.calendar.locale =  Locale(identifier: "en_EN")
    self.calendar.adjustsBoundingRectWhenChangingMonths = true

    let testingView = UIView()
    testingView.backgroundColor = .red

    let attachedToCalendarView = UIView()
    attachedToCalendarView.backgroundColor = .blue

    view.addSubview(calendar)
    view.addSubview(testingView)
    view.addSubview(attachedToCalendarView)

    self.calendar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.calendar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.calendar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.calendar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.size.width).isActive = true
    self.calendar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

    testingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    testingView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    testingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.size.width).isActive = true
    testingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

    attachedToCalendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    attachedToCalendarView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    // Attaching this view's topAnchor to the calendar's bottom anchor
    attachedToCalendarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.calendar.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    attachedToCalendarView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.bounds.size.width).isActive = true
    attachedToCalendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true


    // Title and button to toggle the calendar scope
    self.navigationItem.title = "Test"
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Toggle", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(switchCalendarScope))
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem itself but I did find a workaround. I placed the calendar inside of an empty container view (just a simple UIView) and attached `attachedToCalendarView` to the container's `bottomAnchor` instead of the calendar's itself.

Do note however that using `setScope`, which animates the transition, still causes the same issue. For it to work you have to set it manually like `calendar.scope = x`

example:

```
@objc func switchCalendarScope(){
    if self.calendar.scope == FSCalendarScope.month {
        // self.calendar.setScope(FSCalendarScope.week, animated: true) // this will cause the calendar to be squished again
        self.calendar.scope = .week
        movingConstraint.constant = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size.height * -0.20
    } else {
        // self.calendar.setScope(FSCalendarScope.month, animated: true)
        self.calendar.scope = .month
        movingConstraint.constant = 0
    }
}
```